# How to select the Date Picker In Selenium WebDriver for Date of Birth

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium

I'm using Selenium WebDriver for my web automation test and writing the script in Java.

It was a good day at the beginning till I have to stop at "selecting the birth of date". I want to know how can I select the values as Date, Month and year in the date picker drop down. The date I want to choose is 14-Dec-1966.

The address: http://radcard-cloud.idatamap.com/login

[Photo of the calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnbYY.jpg)

This is my last code that i try. I spent almost 4 days trying to finish it. Help please!

```js
package iDMautomation;
 
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class FirstTest {
     

 public static void main(String[] args) {
         
        //initialize Chrome driver
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\senn\\Desktop\\RadCard Test\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
         WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
        
         
         //Open gmail
         driver.get("http://radcard-cloud.idatamap.com/");
         driver.manage().window().maximize();
          
         //driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpathExpression))
         // Enter userd id
         
         driver.findElement(By.className("patient")).click();
          
         //email pedram
         //driver.findElement(By.className("providerNum")).click();
         WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);// 1 minute 
         wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("email")));

         
         driver.findElement(By.id("email")).click();
         driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("pedram@sahihi.com");
         
         driver.findElement(By.id("PIN")).sendKeys("2281");
         
         driver.findElement(By.id("DOB")).click();
         
        
         Select sel1=new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("DOB")));       
         WebElement FirstTest = driver.findElement(By.id("DOB"));
         
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         driver.findElement(By.className("ui-datepicker-current-day")).click();
         
         Select sel3=new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("selectDay")));
         
         new Select((WebElement) sel3).selectByVisibleText("14");      
         
         FirstTest.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Comment: Do you want that certain date of any date from '66? Do you want to select it using the calendar or just to set it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this looks like Java, not JavaScript, so your tags may be incorrect.

Okay, lets break this down one at a time.
What you would do manually:

1. Click the input field for the "Date Of Birth"
2. Wait for the Calendar to populate and become visible
3. Select a month 
   you have a classname for this menu, and each option has a value and text to select from
4. Select a year
   (repeat of step 3 with different class name and menu options)
   This could be even easier because your dropdown menu has values that align exactly to the year you want
5. You want to "Click" a date from the visible calendar month

Few things of concern and may be why your code is not working

```
driver.findElement(By.className("ui-datepicker-current-day")).click();

Select sel3=new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("selectDay")));

new Select((WebElement) sel3).selectByVisibleText("14");
```

First line here suggest that you are trying to click on todays date, not specifically the 14th

Second and third line looks like you are trying to do a select on the calendar day, but you cannot do that on elements that are not a dropdown select menu. You can only click on it. Also, I am pretty sure that cssSelector("selectDay") doesn't work. It doens't know if you are looking for an ID, classname, tagname etc. I see several of these cssSelector issues.

Also on the third line here, why are you creating and casting a new Select to a WebElement?
You should be able to do

```
sel3.selectByVisibleText("14");
```

Is DOB an ID? You have one with

```
 driver.findElement(By.id("DOB")).click();;
```

Then another

```
Select sel1=new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("DOB")));
```